# how to sync between 2 different pc with one remote repo

Tags: git

Let's say I have 2 PCs - pc_1, pc_2.

I made some work on pc_1 in directory called: dir_1, and push the changes to git:
remote_repo/dir_1/

Now I want to work from pc_2 on this project. Naturally, The files will be located inside specific software directory: dir_2.

when i connect pc_2 local to the remote repo, I type:

> `git pull origin main`

and it creates dir_1 directory on my pc_2.
When I make changes in dir_2 to the files and push, it creates a new /dir_2/  in the remote repo.
(The  in both of the PCs are the same)
Is there a way to sync between the PCs and keep one directory in the remote?

Comment: "Naturally, The files will be located inside specific software directory: dir_2." why would you expect it to be one folder when you "naturally" created two different ones?

Comment: Because the sources - for example p1.cpp, p2,cpp, p3.cpp - are the same at those 2 directories. I want them to appear once on the remote repo

Comment: If you want them to appear once, why do you have two folders in your repository?

Comment: i work in parallel between 2 PCs on the same project. each pc is running different sw, so the containing folder name is different. but the source files names are similar.  i want to have 1 remote and 2 locals.

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense, if you have one folder then use one folder, if you have two then use two. The number of machines you're using your repos on don't matter.

Comment: doesn't git is used in those cases? Sorry i didn't understand you. is it possible to do what im looking for?

Comment: Is sounds like you should use two different branches, say `main1` and `main2` for your two different scenarios. Then you can share whatever is common with merges between those to branches while still keeping them different.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not possible on git to have one remote repo for both of the PCs .. i want to sync between the same source files.. they just under different directory path